# connect ECONNREFUSED 149.102.153.200:3300

Tags: node.js, path, database-connection, cpanel

I have a website on Node.js and a database on POSTGRESSQL, the website is working fine on my local server but when I published it on the Cpanel it shows "connect ECONNREFUSED 149.102.153.200:3300" on all the POST calls while the Get calls are working fine I was assuming it was a backend connectivity issue so I tested my APIS throught POSTMAN and CURL and they work fine also they were woking perfectly on another website and still are

I even contacted the server providers but they refused to help as they claimed it was a code issue although as I mentioned above it is working fine on local....

I am very confused on what to do, So if anyone could help/guide me I will be very grateful as I have been stucked on this issue for the last 3-4 weeks

The Issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQY40.png)

The APIs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk1RI.png)

My Connectivity:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIXQS.png)

I tested my APIS throught POSTMAN and CURL and they work fine also they were woking perfectly on another website and still are

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text.  Also, is it port 3300 or 3000?

Comment: Hey ewokx, it's the port my APIs are running on 3300, also which code my connectivity or my APIs??